# Replace Call from one class to another?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I wonder if it is possible to replace the call from one class to another?

Example

```
TmyButton = class (TButton)
  procedure Click; override;
end;

initialization
  UnRegisterClass (TButton);
  RegisterClass (TButton);
```

But this code does not work properly, does anyone have any tips?

thank you

Please see the full example below, I'm calling at startup but unfortunately it has not worked correctly.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
 TmyButton = class( TButton )
  procedure Click; override;

 end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 inherited;
 ShowMessage( 'Hello' );
end;

{ TmyButton }

procedure TmyButton.Click;
begin

 ShowMessage( 'myClass' );
 inherited;

end;

initialization
 UnRegisterClass( TButton );
 RegisterClass( TMyButton );

end.
```

Comment: What flame? Method overriding is known to work (even in FMX). What exactly is the problem you're asking? Could you elaborate, please (_"does not work properly"_ is not a valid problem description)?

Comment: sorry google translator :(

Comment: This isn't a translation issue. You still have not told us what you actually mean by "does not work properly". Do you get an error message? Have you debugged your code to see *where* the error comes from, if any at all? Does your entire computer bluescreen? We don't know what you mean.

Comment: Did you guys understand my doubt?

thank you

Comment: No, I did not, that's why I asked you to please tell us what doesn't "work properly"?

Comment: The method of my class procedure TmyButton.Click;
it is never invoked even though I are registering my class

Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way.  What you need is an **interposer class** instead.  Meaning your custom class has the *same name* as the class you are trying to replace.  The DFM system doesn't use full qualified class names, so at runtime, the streaming system will create instances of the last class that has been defined with a given class name.

So, change this:

```
type
 TmyButton = class( TButton )
  procedure Click; override;
 end;
```

To this:

```
type
 TButton = class( FMX.StdCtrls.TButton )
  procedure Click; override;
 end;
```

And this:

```
{ TmyButton }

procedure TmyButton.Click;
begin

 ShowMessage( 'myClass' );
 inherited;

end;
```

To this:

```
{ TButton }

procedure TButton.Click;
begin

 ShowMessage( 'myClass' );
 inherited;

end;
```

And get rid of your `initialization` section completely.

Here is the full code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
 TButton = class( FMX.StdCtrls.TButton )
  procedure Click; override;

 end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 inherited;
 ShowMessage( 'Hello' );
end;

{ TButton }

procedure TButton.Click;
begin

 ShowMessage( 'myClass' );
 inherited;

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not experienced with FMX, but I'd be really surprised if the following doesn't apply...

The reason your code isn't called is relatively simple,  you don't create an object of that type.

Declaring a class `TMyButton = class(TButton)` doesn't replace code for the TButton class, it merely allow you to create instances of a class `TMyButton` that inherits from `TButton`.

Since `Button1: TButton;` is a `TButton`, clicking on it calls code from `TButton`, not code from `TMyButton`.